# post request work in android but not in iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, webview, httprequest, react-native-webview

I have a react native application with WebView , the WebView have a post request.
The WebView works as expected in android and gets the page, but when I'm trying in iOS, it does not work.

When I log the data being passed, it all looks fine.

The page I'm trying to load is not mine.

Here's my code

```
    <WebView
      originWhitelist={["*"]}
      headers= {{
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      }}
      source={{
        uri: cloud_function_server_url + props.provider.link,
        method: "POST",
        body:
          "order_id=" +
          props.payData.order_id +
          "&amount=" +
          props.payData.amount +
          "&product=" +
          props.payData.product_name +
          "&mobile_no=" +
          props.payData.mobile_no +
          "&email=" +
          props.payData.email +
          "&productamount=" +
          props.payData.productamount +
          "&type=" +
          props.payData.type,
      }}
      onLoadStart={onLoadStart}
    />
```

It says amount and email in invalid. But the same data gets passed for Android and it works well.

Comment: The issue is fixed now !

Comment: headers should be inside source not outside.